# email encodeURIComponent no longer works after android update

Tags: android, jquery, email

After the most recent update my web app no longer fills in the body of emails.
The email client comes up with the proper subject but the body is empty. This web app worked in prior to the most recent (awful) android update. I think its called lollipop.
The following is the jquery code.

```
$(document).on("click", "#sendEmail",function(){
    $(location).attr('href', 'mailto:?subject='
                         + encodeURIComponent(emailSubject)
                         + "&body=" 
                         + encodeURIComponent(emailBody)
    );
});
```

I suspect this has something to do with gmail update. Where do I start looking? Did anyone else experience these problems?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else who may be looking for an answer. It seems that this is a gmail bug. I recommend switching to mailDroid or another email client.